# ¿Cómo detectar paridad de un numero sin el operador %?

Tags: javascript, ajax

Tengo una variable que me da el servidor con un valor, necesito saber si el numero es **par** o **impar**, pero sin utilizar `%2`:

```
$.ajax({ 
    url:'/numero',
    type:'POST',
    success:function(num){
       // ¿Qué hago con num para saber qué es?
       // num.numero me da el valor del numero ej;5,7,2...
    }

})
```

Comment: Qué has intentado?

Comment: ese es el lío , que no se me ocurre como hacerlo , porque anteriormente decía `if(num%2==0)` par `else` impar, pero sin eso ni idea

Comment: Mira, primero tienes que aclarar algo. Intenta haciendo console.log(num) dentro de success y publica exactamente lo te muestra. Hay versiones de jquery que returnan las respuesta como un objeto por lo que puede ser que num sea un objeto no un valor per se.

Comment: solo por curiosidad: ¿por qué no puedes usar ese operador?.. Además considero que la respuesta de Trauma es la mejor ... vas a reconsiderar cambiar el aceptado ?

Answer (score 41, accepted):

Es muy sencillo: utiliza el **[operador de bit AND](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Operadores/Bitwise_Operators)**.

En binario, los número **pares** tienen **el último bit a 0**, mientras que los impares **tienen el último bit a 1**:

> 1512 & 1 ==> 0 ( es par )
>   1511 & 1 ==> 1 ( es impar )

Por lo tanto:

```js
function espar( x ) {
  return !( x & 1 );
}
console.log(espar(1512));
console.log(espar(1511));
```

> espar( 1512 ) ==> true
>   espar( 1511 ) ==> false

<sub>No puedo resistirme a la *moraleja*: solo hay `10` clases de personas: las que saben binario y las que no ;-)</sub>

Comment: Acabo de aprender algo nuevo. Muy buena respuesta.

Comment: Trauma tenia un error en armar el benchmark con ayuda de PabloLozano tu forma es la mas rapida http://jsben.ch/1ZhdR , incluso es mas rapido que  el mod 2 que lo analice

Comment: Una pequeña joya

Comment: Muy interesante respuesta. Esto ahorra considerablemente recursos de hardware.

Answer (score 5):

Divide el numero entre 2. Los numero impares siempre retornaran un numero decimal mientras que los pares no. Entonces solo habria que verificar si es un decimal convirtiendo el resultado a string y buscar por el punto:

```js
var value = prompt("Ingrese numero:");

var esPar = (parseInt(value)/2).toString().indexOf('.')==-1;

if(esPar){
  console.log("el numero es par");
}
else{
  console.log("el numero es impar");
}
```

Comment: la verdad hace lo que quiere pero usastes un `parseInt` una `divivion` un `toString` un `IndexOf` y un `if ` no digo que este mal pero no es muy optima

Comment: @JackNavaRow `parseInt` para asegurarme que sea un numero(en mi ejemplo, prompt retorna string, no Number) y poder hacer la operacion de divicion. `toString()` para poder utilizar le metodo `indexOf` de `string` ya que `Number` no contiene ese método. Sabes de alguna otra manera de hacerlo?

Comment: la opcion de Trauma me parece la mas correcta y simple, de hecho mejor que el % 2 , por que no hace una division  y luego un if, es simplemente un if validando el valor del bit

Comment: Puedes usar ```Number#isInteger``` para comprobar si es un número entero: https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Number/isInteger

Answer (score 4):

Por que simplemente no haces una operación matemática de división ? Si al dividir un número entre 2 el resultado de la división es exacta significa que el número es par entonces esto lo validamos con una expresión regular, simplemente es preguntar "si el resultado de la división contiene un punto significa que no fue exacta y que por consiguiente el número es impar"

```js
$("#preguntar").click(function(){
  var numero = $("#numero").val();
  
  var division = (Number(numero) / 2);
  var expresion = new RegExp(/\./);
  
  if(expresion.test(division.toString())){
    console.log('El número ingresado es impar');
  }else{
    console.log('El número ingresado es par');
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="text" id="numero">

<button id="preguntar">Par o impar</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Conociendo el último dígito de tu número puedes descifrar si el número entero es par o impar ya que se sabe que los números terminados en 0,2,4,6 y 8 son pares, por tanto

Puedes hacer lo siguiente:

```
$.ajax({ 
    url:'/numero',
    type:'POST',
    success:function(num){
       //Declaro todos los numeros en los que debe terminar los #s pares
       var pars = [0,2,4,6,8];
       //Verifico si el numero actual termina en uno de esos y asi veo cuando es par y cuando no
       if(pars.indexOf(parseInt(num.toString().charAt(num.toString().length-1))) >= 0)
          console.log("es par");
        else 
          console.log("es impar");
    }

});
```

Comment: Supongamos que el servidor returne 15550, como sabra que es par o impar?

Comment: Verificará que el último caracter es par y sabrá que el número es par.

Comment: Si te hubieses explicado asi, quizas no te hubieras llevado los puntos negativos. Intenta editar tu pregunta y agregar ese comentario. Aunque tienes que tener en cuenta que si el servidor retorna un numero decimal, digamos: 51542.15, tu codigo fallaria.

Answer (score 0):

//encontrar si un numero es par o impar sin usar modulo

````
const parImpar = (n) => {

   return n === 0 ? console.log(`El numero ${n} no es divisible` ) : String(n/2).includes('.') === true ? console.log('el numero es impar'): console.log('el numero es par')

 }

parImpar(5)```
````