# Optimizar método para calcular números primos

Tags: python

Tengo ese método para calcular números primos, quiero saber si se puede optimizar más. ¿Qué podría usar?

```
def es_primo(n):    
    if n< 2: 
        return False
    for i in range(2, n):
        if n% i == 0:
            return False 
    return True
```

Una mano, gracias.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Si te refieres a simplemente optimizar tu algoritmo de división por tentativa  hay  algunas mejoras importantes que puedes hacer y que son muy simples:

- **Calcular el resto de la división solo con los impares y el 2**. Ten en cuenta que los posibles factores van a ser primos y no hay primos pares por definición(menos el 2).
- Tampoco es necesario comprobar desde 2 hasta `n`, basta con hacerlo hasta la **raiz cuadrada de `n`**. Esto es así porque de ser un número compuesto siempre hay, al menos, un factor que es menor o igual a la raiz cuadrada. Si encontramos un divisor ya sabemos que es compuesto.
- Puedes también usar un generador junto a `any`.

Tu función puede quedar:

```
def es_primo(n):
    # Comprobamos si n es 2 (unico primo par)
    if n == 2:
        return True

    # Comprobamos si es menor de 2 o es par
    if n < 2 or not n % 2:
        return False

    # Comprobamos si es divisible entre cualquier entero impar entre 3 y sqrt(n)
    return not any(n % i == 0 for i in range(3, int(n**0.5) + 1, 2))
```

La clave está en `range`, el primer parámetro (start) es 3, el segundo (stop) es la raíz cuadrada de `n` más 1 y el tercer parámetro (step) es 2. Esto hace que el `range` genere una secuencia de número impares que empieza en 3 y va de dos en dos hasta raíz cuadrada de `n`. Para `n = 70` generaría `(3, 5, 7)`.

`n**0.5` es equivalente a hacer la raíz cuadrada de `n`.

`any` retorna retorna `True` en el momento que alguna de las condiciones se cumple, en este caso en el momento que algún resto es 0.

---

Para números grandes va a ser un método lento obviamente. En estos casos hay múltiples test de primalidad que podemos implementar que pueden ser más o menos complejos, eficientes o ser deterministas o probabilisticos (test de Fermat, test de Miller-Rabin, AKS, etc).

Si por casualidad tu finalidad es obtener una lista de número primos desde 2 hasta un número dado, una criba de Eratóstenes es muy fácil de implementar y da buenos resultados siempre que `n` no sea exageradamente alto.

Comment: podemos cambiar  n % 2 port n & 1 , la comparacion binaria es optima en comparacion a la division [un ejemplo en Javascript](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/124758/28035)