# Números primos en Python

Tags: python

Estoy intentando crear un programa que me devuelva "true" si el número es primo o no. He escrito esto, pero creo que tengo un error en la penúltima fila pero no se porqué

```
import math
n=int(input("n="))
    is_prime = True
    for i in range(2,n):
       if n%i == 0:
         return False
    print(is_prime)
```

Comment: ¿Que tipo de error? ¿Qué te devuelve?

Comment: Quiero que n sea cualquier numero

Comment: O es mejor ponerlo en el código?

Comment: multiple statements found while compiling a single statement

Comment: Ese es el error @Aritzbn

Comment: @Joaquin puedes editar poniendo todo lo que tienes en la función?

Comment: Ya está, eso tengo en la función

Comment: Primero de todo, la identación está mal. Segundo ¿ese es todo el código o está dentro de una función?, porque si no está dentro de una función no puedes usar return...

Comment: Ese es todo el código

Answer (score 9):

El primer error es que `return` ha de usarse solo **dentro de una función/método**. Deberías modificar la variable `is_prime` en el `if`, no usar `return`:

```
n = int(input("n="))
is_prime = True
for i in range(2, n):
   if n % i == 0:
     is_prime = False
     break

print(is_prime)
```

O si usas una función:

```
def is_prime(n): 
    for i in range(2, n):
        if n % i == 0:
            return False
    return True

n = int(input("n="))
print(is_prime(n))
```

El método que usas es ineficiente, usando división por tentativa no necesitas testear todos los números entre 2 y `n`, basta con probar si es par o divisible entre alguno de los números impares entre 3 y raíz cuadrada de `n`.

También debes romper el ciclo en el momento que encuentras que el número es divisible, no tiene sentido seguir probando una vez que sabemos que es compuesto. De esto se encarga `break` o `return` en la función.

Por otro lado tienes que tener en cuanta que pasa si se **ingresa un número menor que 2**, mírate esta pregunta:

[Optimizar método para calcular números primos](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/141757/15089)

Answer (score 4):

No tienes N declarado, supuse que lo definirias al declarar una función.
Para declarar funciones se usa el `def nombrefuncion(parametros)`, algo que no he visto en tu código, después la llamas.

Supongo que lo que te faltaba era darle valor a n, lo he hecho pasando por parámetro y así si que debería de funcionar.

```
def funcion(n):

    is_prime = True
    for i in range(2,n):
        if n%i == 0:
            is_prime = False
    return is_prime

print(funcion(5))
```

Por otro lado tenías mal la identación, teniendo el `return` dentro del `if`, por lo que nunca devolvería valor en caso de que no entrase en la condición.

Comment: Vale, así funciona! Muchas gracias a todos!

Comment: Si te funciona no olvides dar la respuesta por válida :) un saludo

Answer (score 0):

Python te obliga a que si tienes un return dentro de un if tengas otro en un else o un return al final del código, además con tu algoritmo si N=2 o 1 te puede dar problemas y para hacer return debe estar dentro de una función

```
import math
def is_prime(n):
    is_prime = True
    if n > 2:
        for i in range(2,n):
        if n%i == 0:
            is_prime = False
    return is_prime
print(is_prime(int(input("n=")))
```

Answer (score 0):

Puedes intentar definir una función de esta manera:
Primero creas una función que indique el primer número primo de un número indicado
Después, compruebas si el primer primo del número es el mismo que ese mismo número.
Ya está!

```
def esPrimo(numero):

  if (numero == 1): #Excepción para el número 1
    return True
  if (numero < 1): #Excepción para números negativos y el 0
    return False

  if (primerPrimoDeUnNumero(numero) == numero) : #si el primer primo de un número es él mismo, entonces ese número es primo.
    return True
  return False

def primerPrimoDeUnNumero(n): #comprobar si un número es primo.
  primo = 2
  while ((n%primo) != 0):
    primo += 1
  return primo


#Ejemplos de como usar la función:
print(esPrimo(3))
print(esPrimo(4))
print(esPrimo(2))
# Algunos más complicados:
print(esPrimo(3251))
print(esPrimo(273))
```

Answer (score 0):

Diseñé este código que te regresa 'True' cuando el número es primo.

```
def Num_Primo(Numero):
if Numero>1:
    if Numero==2:
        print("El número 2 es primo")
        return True
    else:
        if Numero%2==0:
            print("El número ",Numero," no es primo porque es par.")
            return False
        else:
            Factorial=1
            Indicador=Numero
            while Indicador>1:
                Factorial=(Indicador-1)*Factorial
                Indicador=Indicador-1
            '''
            Inicia el Teorema de Wilson.
            '''
            if (Factorial+1)%Numero==0:
                print("El número ",Numero," es primo.")
                return True
            else:
                print("El número ",Numero," no es primo.")
                return False
            '''
            Termina el Teorema de Wilson.
            '''
else:
    print("El número que ingresas no es primo.")
    return False
```

Este método no es eficiente pues hace uso de los factoriales, por lo tanto, para números medianamente grandes, estoy hablando de números de 5 a 7 dígitos, el programa puede tardarse algunos segundos.

Answer (score 0):

```py
def is_prime(number):
  count = 0
  for i in range(1,number + 1):
    if i == 1 or i == number:
      continue
    if number % i == 0:
      count += 1
  if count == 0:
    return True
  else:
    return False

is_prime(7)
```

Comment: ¿Cómo resuelve esto el problema que tiene el OP? Lee [answer] y edita tu respuesta para explicar tu código. [¿Por qué es bueno explicar el código?](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/2882/)

Answer (score -1):

En el `for`, no hace falta que llegues hasta `N`. Con llegar hasta `n/2` o hasta `(n/2)-1` (porque has empezado por `2`) sería suficiente.

Comment: En realidad basta con llegar a raiz de N. Supón que esa raiz vale M. Entonces M*M=N, y así se ve que cualquier factor mayor de M ha de ir multiplicado por otro menor de M, para dar el mismo N. Si no apareció ningún factor antes de M, no va a aparecer tampoco después.