# Tengo un problema con numeros primos en python

Tags: python, variables, bucle-for

hola queria saber como puedo buscar los primeros primos de un numero y guardas los primos encontrados en una lista, mi programa que esta fallando es el siguiente, se que estoy haciendo algo muy mal, es que recien estoy entrando en este mundo de la programacion y me cuesta poder llegar a buscarle la logica, si tambien tienen algun consejo se los agradeceria, puedo llegar a estar horas para desarrollar un problema simple y asi me desanimo mucho, gracias:
les dejo mejor la consigna:
*Definir una función que tome un entero n y devuelva los primeros n primos.*

```
def primos(n):
    losprimos=[]
    for i in range(2,n):
        if (n%i==0):
            print("")
        else:
            losprimos.append( i)
n=9
print(primos(n))
```

Comment: eso siempe sucede entre primos xD

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [Números primos en Python](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/156186/n%c3%bameros-primos-en-python)

Answer (score 0):

te falto devolver la lista con return en la funcion

```
def primos(n):
        losprimos=[]
        for i in range(2,n):
            if (n%i==0):
                print("")
            else:
                losprimos.append( i)
        return losprimos
    n=9
    print(primos(n))
```

Ademas un numero es primo solo si se puede dividir entre 1 y el mismo o lo que es lo mismo que solo tengan dos divisores

Solucion:

```
def primos(n):
    losprimos=[]
    cont = 0

    for i in range(1, n + 1):
        for j in range(1, i + 1):
          if i % j == 0:
            cont += 1
        if cont == 2:
          losprimos.append(i)
        cont = 0
    return losprimos
n=9
print(primos(n))
```

Comment: hola pero no me devuelve los primos, me retorna tambien el 6 y 8

Comment: claro un numero es primo si SOLO se puede dividir entre el mismo y 1 o lo que es lo mismo que solo tengan dos divisores,he editado mi respuesta con la solucion

Comment: Puedes mejorar tu código añadiendo un break en el `for j in range(1, i + 1):` cuando el contador es mayor que 2. De esta manera, para números con varios divisores no tendrá que buscarlos todos.

Answer (score 0):

Por lo que entendí, tu dilema es que: dado un numero n entero, mostrar todos los primos que se encuentran entre 2 y n.

la solucion que pude hacer en esta:

```
def primos(n):
    losprimos=[]
    for x in range(2,n): #va del numero 2 al elejido
        val=True
        for y in range(2,x): #va del numero 2 al x
            if x%y == 0: #si el modulo de x e y es 0, no cumple la regla de los numeros primos
                val=False
                break
        if val: #si val es Flase no lo agrega, si es True lo hace
            losprimos.append(x)    
    return losprimos        
n=20
print(primos(n))
```

Espero que te sirva de ayuda.

Answer (score 0):

Una solución, quizás no sea la correcta, pero sería utilizar un contador. Teniendo en cuenta que *n es primo siempre y cuando tenga sólo dos divisores ( 1 y n).* Entonces podríamos pensar una función que tome un número y nos devuelva una lista de números primos que esten dentro de ese rango. Yendo al código, podemos escribir algo parecido a esto, (digo parecido porque se pueden aprovechar funciones de python para reducir las lineas de código).

```
def primos(VALOR):

losprimos = []
for NUM in range(1,VALOR+1):
    c=0
    for inx in range(1,NUM+1):
        if NUM % inx == 0:
            c+=1
    if c == 2:
        losprimos.append(NUM)

return losprimos
```

output:

```
  primos(9)
    >>[2, 3, 5, 7]
```

Answer (score 0):

Cuando te dicen que obtengas *"los primeros n números primos"*, en principio no sabes cuántos números vas a tener que comprobar hasta llegar a obtener los n primeros.

Una solución podría ser crear un iterador "infinito" de primos y quedarse con los n primeros:

```py
import sys
from itertools import islice

Prime = int  # un alias de números primos

INFINITE = sys.maxsize  # maxsize es el máximo número de elementos en una lista.
                        # No es infinito, pero sirve para nuestros cálculos.

def isprime(n: int) -> bool:
    """Comprobar que n no tiene ningún divisor, excepto 1 y él mismo"""
    return not any(n % i == 0 for i in range(2, n))

def primes(numItems: int) -> list[Prime]:
    allprimes = (i for i in range(2, INFINITE) if isprime(i))
    return list(islice(allprimes, numItems))
```

La función `any()` comprueba si en la secuencia hay algún elemento que cumpla la condición, en este caso, que no exista ningún divisor (`n % i == 0`). Si encuentra alguno, devuelve `True` sin necesidad de comprobar ningún divisor más.

Para obtener los 10 primeros primos:

```py
>>> print(primes(10))
[2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13, 17, 19, 23, 29]
```

Se puede optimizar muchísimo más, aunque es bastante avanzado para ponerlo aquí. Por si resulta de interés, en uno de los artículos que escribí sobre la optimización de secuencias numéricas, hay uno sobre [la obtención de números primos](https://blog.ch3m4.org/2021/02/15/evaluacion-perezosa-en-python-parte-4/).

Answer (score -1):

Posiblemente alguna de las respuestas que ya han puesto arriba te funcionen. Este ejemplo lo estoy colocando como una mejora en la eficiencia del algoritmo.
Sucede que el cálculo de números primos es un proceso bastante extenuante para el CPU, si se hace con números grandes.

En este código, se comienzan los cálculos a partir de 3, el divisor se incrementa de 2 en dos (3, 5, 7) y solo llegará hasta la mitad del numero, menos 1.
Apenas un numero es divisible, el ciclo `for` se rompe con el `break` y se descarta ese número.

> Ejemplo: 11 -> 11%3!=0, 11%5!=0; Fin (Es primo) [Solo 2 iteraciones]
>
> Ejemplo: 25 -> 25%3!=0, 25%5==0 (False // Break) (NO es primo) [Solo 2 iteraciones]

El código

```
def primos(n):
    losprimos = [2] if n > 0 else [] 
    cant_calculada = len(losprimos)
    incr = 3
    while cant_calculada < n:
        esprimo = True
        final = int(incr/2)
        for i in range (3, final, 2):
            if incr%i == 0:
                esprimo = False
                break
        if esprimo:
            losprimos.append(incr)
            cant_calculada += 1
        incr += 2
    return losprimos

n = 9
print(primos(n))
```

> [2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13, 17, 19, 23]

Comment: gracias te agradezco mucho la explicacion, pero por ahora tenemos que manejarnos con lo poco que nos dan para entender bien en general las bases. No me podrias dar un consejo si es que la tenes mas clara de como es el tema de la logica, porque la verdad me cuesta encontrarle la vuelta hacia estos temas faciles,puedo llegar a estar dos horas con este ejercicio