# ¿Pueden decirme exactamente qué hace mi programa?

Tags: python, bucle-for, bucles

Empecé a leer el libro del tutorial Python y todo iba bien, hasta que me trabé en un punto donde no se qué hace exactamente este programa:

```
for n in range(2,10):
    for x in range(2, n):
        if n % x == 0:
            print(n, "es igual a", x, "*", n//x)
            break
    else:
        print(n, "es un numero primo")
input()
```

Cuando divide n % x, ¿x vale 2 o es equivalente al valor de n en ese momento

Answer (score 2):

Básicamente es un test de primalidad para los enteros de un dígito usando fuerza bruta y sin ninguna optimización usando división por tentativa (probar si hay algún entero entre 2 y  `n` - 1 que divida a `n`). Vamos a ir por partes:

- `for n in range(2, 10)`: `for` que se encarga de iterar sobre un rango de enteros empezando en 2 y terminando con 9. Son los números que queremos ver si son o no primos.
- `for x in range(2, n)`: `for` anidado que por cada ciclo del anterior (por cada valor de `n`) itera sobre el rango de enteros que empiezan en 2 y termina en `n - 1`, todos los posibles divisores de `n` excepto el mismo y 1.
- `if n % x == 0:` este es el núcleo del algoritmo, la condición se cumple si `n` dividido entre `x` es una división exacta, no tiene resto, por lo que decimos que `x` es divisor de `n`. En este caso `%` es el operador módulo o resto de la división entera. Si un número tiene un divisor distinto de la unidad y el mismo es compuesto (no primo).
- `print(n, "es igual a", x, "*", n//x)`: si `n` es compuesto imprime su primer divisor encontrado que multiplicado por otro número nos da `n`. Como trabajamos con números del 2 al 9 retorna sus factores, ya que todos los compuestos en este rango solo tienen un factor (al cuadrado) o dos factores. `n//x` es la división entera (`12 // 5 = 2`), en contraposición de la división real (`12 / 5 = 2.4`). En Python 3, el operador `/` siempre retorna la división real, en Python 2 depende del tipo de los operandos (`12 / 5 = 2`, `12 / 5.0 = 2.4`).
- `break`: en el caso que el número sea compuesto rompemos el segundo ciclo `for`, no tiene sentido seguir probando con el resto de candidatos.
- `else`: como se puede observar este `else` está al nivel del segundo `for`, no formando parte de un bloque `if-elif-else`. En este contexto el `else` viene a decir "*si el ciclo se completó*". Es decir, si el segundo `for` no se rompe a causa del `break` (no ha encontrado ningún divisor para `n`), se entra en este `else`, imprimiéndose por tanto que `n` es primo `print(n, "es un numero primo")`.

Por si te interesa, la división por tentativa se puede optimizar con poco trabajo:

[Optimizar método para calcular números primos](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/141757/15089)