# Encontrar el siguiente número primo - Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

Tengo que encontrar el siguiente número primo a uno dado por el usuario, tengo esto pero no me sale:

```
a=int(input('escribe un numero'))

for i in range(a,a*2):
  if a%i==0:
    a=a+1
    if a%i==0:
      print(a)
```

Comment: Una pista: necesitas una función que te diga si un número dado es primo o no lo es. Por otro lado, como vas a iterar valores *hasta* encontrar un primo, lo adecuado es un bucle *while* y no un bucle *for*. Saludos

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [Optimizar método para calcular números primos](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/141757/optimizar-m%c3%a9todo-para-calcular-n%c3%bameros-primos)