# Generar números aleatorios de un rango dado

Tags: javascript

Necesito que en mi `input` se muestre un número aleatorio *impar* dentro del rango que establecí. Intenté usar un ciclo **for** con un **if**, pero mi programa *«truena»*.

Esto es lo que por ahora tengo:

```js
var min = 200;
var max = 300;
var semrandom;

semrandom = Math.floor(Math.random() * max) + min;
if ((semrandom % 2) == 0) {
  continue; 
}

document.getElementById('semilla').setAttribute("value", `${semrandom}`);
```

Si genera un número aleatorio, pero no un *número aleatorio impar*. La pregunta es, ¿cómo lo puedo conseguir?

Comment: ¿Qué error obtienes exactamente al usar un if?, por que yo lo he probado de ese modo y funciona

Comment: Ya actualice el codigo, gracias

Comment: la instruccion [`continue`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Sentencias/continue) , se usa para saltar la iteracion de un ciclo repetitivo, al no tener un ciclo (for/while por ejemplo)  te da el error

Comment: adicional a tu  pregunta te recomiendo leer la respuesta de [@Trauma.JS](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/124758/28035) de como calcular un numero par /impar con binario, y tambien comentarte que existe una notacion matematica para que un numero sea impar `2x+1`

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Hay casos en los que el uso de la recursión es innecesario. Este es uno de ellos.
**Los números impares tienen la forma 2n + 1** de modo que si n es un número aleatorio también lo será 2n + 1 y **será un aleatorio impar**. usando este principio elemental la solución para obtener un número aleatorio impar en el rango deseado (200 a 300) es la siguiente:

```js
var min = 200;
var max = 300;
// se calcula el rango dividiendo a la mitad y restando 1 porque va a
// incluir el 0 como extremo inferior y debe entonces excluir el extremo 
// superior para no desbordar
var rango = ((max - min) / 2) - 1;
var semrandom;
// Como la función Math.random() genera valores entre 0 y 1 y necesitamos enteros en el ramgo establecido hacemos:
semirandom = 2 * Math.floor(Math.random() * rango) +1 +min;
// notese el uso de la forma 2n+1 y +min para situarse en el rango deseado.
// se ha asumido que min es par.
console.log(semirandom)
```

A partir de ahí es muy sencillo hacer una generalización para rangos arbitrarios.

Solucion general:

Como ofrecí hace un rato (en los comentarios) una función general que aplique la idea sería la siguiente:

```js
function obtenerImparAleatorioEnRango(min, max){
    // Declaro las variables a emplear
    let base, cotasup, rango, semirandom;
    // aseguro que los extremos del rango sean pares
    if(max > min){
        base = ((min % 2)==0) ? min : min -1;
        cotasup = ((max % 2)==0) ? max : max +1;
    }else{
        base = ((max % 2)==0) ? max : max -1;
        cotasup = ((min % 2)==0) ? min : min +1;        
    }
    // se fija el rango de selección a la mitad del intervalo entre extremos pares
    // quitando un elemento porque se incluye el cero (como se indicó en la solución arriba)
    rango = ((cotasup - base) / 2) - 1;
    // se obtiene ahora el valor pseudoaleatorio a devolver
    // como random es un valor entre 0 y uno
    semirandom = 2 * Math.floor(Math.random() * rango) +1 +base;
    // salida de depuración
    return semirandom;
}
console.log(obtenerImparAleatorioEnRango(300,500))
```

Comment: Algo así venía a responder, ya que me parece poco prolijo repetir el `random` hasta que devuelva un impar como sugieren las otras respuestas. El único problema con esta solución es que ignora el valor máximo si éste es impar. Es decir, si max es 300 o 301, el valor máximo devuelto siempre será 299. Creo que se corregiría haciendo `var rango = Math.ceil((max - min) / 2) - 1`. También uniría la línea `var semrandom` con la siguiente.

Comment: @Andrew Tienes razón. El defecto de mi respuesta es haberse centrado el el rango 200 a 300. Pero, se puede agregar un complemento que la generalice para rangos aleatorios. Lo haré en la tarde.

Comment: De esta forma nunca puede salir el 299, que está dentro del rango. En esta lógica entiendo que el rango debería ser `(max - min) / 2`

Comment: Hola @Emeeus en caso de que Math.random() devuelva 49 se tendrá `200 + (2*49) + 1 = 299`

Answer (score 8):

El error es debido a que la instrucción [`continue`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Sentencias/continue) , se usa para saltar la iteración de un ciclo repetitivo, al no tener un ciclo (for/while por ejemplo) te da el error

---

Una vez claro esto que tal si pensamos un poco como matemáticos, la formula para un numero impar es :

```
2X + 1
```

Donde `2X` nos garantiza que el numero sea par, y luego le sumamos 1 para convertirlo en impar en nuestro caso, debemos de sumarle uno cuando sea par

Para optimizar el codigo nos apoyaremos de un ejemplo del loco de [@Trauma.JS](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/124758/28035) para saber que numero es *par/impar*, aplicamos otras caracteristicas  y tenemos lo siguiente:

```js
const max = 99;
let  semrandom;

let X = Math.floor(Math.random() * max);
semrandom =  X + 200 + !(X & 1);
console.log(semrandom)
```

```html
<div id="semilla"> </div>
```

La idea del `!(X & 1)` esto me retorna un `true` si el numero es par al ser par y previo a esto existe una suma Javascript cambie el `true` por `1`

Answer (score 4):

### Encontrar números aleatorios impares

Una posible solución para encontrar números aleatorios **impares** es utilizando la [recursión](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursi%C3%B3n). Por lo tanto, debe crear una función que se denominará **imparAleatorio().**

Por ejemplo:

```js
const imparAleatorio = (min, max) => {
  // Instrucciones para la recursión
};
```

Que tendrá implementada las siguientes instrucciones para que quede algo parecido a esto:

```js
const imparAleatorio = (min, max) => {
  // Obtener números aleatorios comprendidos entre min y max:
  var semrandom = Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min)) + min;

  // Se evalúea si el númeo aleatorio obtenido es par o impar:
  if (semrandom % 2 == 0) {
    // Se utiliza la recursión hasta encontrar
    // un número impar:
    semrandom = imparAleatorio(min, max);

    // Una vez encontrado el número aleatorio impar
    // le indicamos al función que lo retorne:
    return semrandom;
  }

  // Se retorna de una vez si el número aleatorio obtenido
  //  era impar en el primer intento:
  return semrandom;
};
```

Una vez preparada la implementaremos de forma similar a esto:

```js
var aleatorio = imparAleatorio(min, max);
```

Donde **min** y **max** son los intervalos comprendidos de números aleatorios que queremos obtener.

### Reproducir ejemplo:

Para no alargar mucho esta respuesta crearemos un ejemplo reproducible en el que podrás probarlo e implementarlo directamente en tu proyecto:

```js
var
  min = 200,
  max = 300;

const imparAleatorio = (min, max) => {
  var semrandom = Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min)) + min;

  if (semrandom % 2 == 0) {
    semrandom = imparAleatorio(min, max);
    return semrandom;
  }

  return semrandom;
};

// Reproducir la prueba:
probar.onclick = () => {
  consola.textContent = imparAleatorio( min, max );
}
```

```css
::-moz-focus-inner {
  border: 0;
}

:root {
  font-family: "Open Sans", sans-serif, arial;
}

#consola {
  margin-top: 10px;
  border: 1px solid #0080d4;
  padding: 5px 10px;
  min-height: 40px;

  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  background-color: rgba(0, 128, 213, 0.1);
}

button {
  display: block;
  border: 0;
  background-color: rgba(0, 128, 213, 1);
  color: white;
  height: 40px;
  border-radius: 4px;
  padding: 0 10px;
  transition: 300ms ease;

  margin: 20px 0;
}

button:active {
  transform-origin: left top;
  transform: scaleX(0.98);
  transition: none;
}
```

```html
<button id="probar">Mostrar resultados</button>
<div id="consola"></div>
```

Del ejemplo anterior, solo debe tomar en cuenta el código **JavaScript**, que es la que produce el resultado deseado. Después de todo, los números que se necesitan son los *números aleatorios impares*.

El mismo ejemplo se puede reproducir en tu caja de texto de esta forma:

```js
var
  min = 200,
  max = 300;

const imparAleatorio = (min, max) => {
  var semrandom = Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min)) + min;

  if (semrandom % 2 == 0) {
    semrandom = imparAleatorio(min, max);
    return semrandom;
  }

  return semrandom;
};

semilla.setAttribute("value", imparAleatorio( min, max ));
```

```html
<input type="text" id="semilla" />
```

No es necesario colocar `document.getElementById("semilla")` si el `id` de la caja de texto es `id="semilla"`.

---

#### Recursos:

- [Recursión](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursi%C3%B3n)
- [Math.floor() - JavaScript MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Math/floor)
- [Math.random() - JavaScript MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Math/random)

Comment: Excelente explicación, una duda que me surge es, como puedo mostrar el numero generado inmediatamente en un input sin necesidad de hacer clic al botón? Intente con el document.getElementById de mi código pero no lo puedo hacer funcionar.

Comment: Primero debes asegurarte que el código **HTML** cargue primero que el código JavaScript. En este caso, si colocas la etiqueta `script` entre las cabeceras `head` debes escribirlo así: `<script src="tuscript.js" defer></script>`, donde **defer** es el parámetro que le indica al navegador que cargue de forma diferida el `script`.

Comment: Luego, en tu `script` debes escribir: `semilla.setAttribute("value", imparAleatorio( min, max ));`

Comment: Amplié un poco para responder la interrogante surgida.

Comment: No tiene sentido usar recursión, eso ralentifica un algoritmo que puede ser extremadamente simple

Answer (score 2):

El código que provees parece ser la solución sin embargo el uso de la palabra reservada `continue` dentro de una estructura condicional simple devuelve este error:

> "SyntaxError: Illegal continue statement: no surrounding iteration statement

Me parece que si deseas controlar las acciones que tu código tomará dependiendo si es par o impar entonces lo podemos colocar dentro de una función, para que de ser par el número obtenido hagamos un `return false;` y en caso contrario se pueda por ejemplo imprimir dicho valor.

```
let min = 200;
let max = 300;
let semrandom = Math.floor(Math.random() * max) + min;
function soloImpares() {
  if (semrandom % 2 !== 0) {
   document.getElementById('semilla').setAttribute("value", `${semrandom}`)
  } else {
   return false
  }
}
soloImpares()
```

- Ya que el uso de `return` solo es posible dentro de un contexto de la función
- El uso de `continue` solo se puede expresar dentro del contexto de un condicional que existe dentro del cuerpo de un bucle; para mayor referencia [leer aquí](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Sentencias/continue)

**Ejemplo**

```html
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
      <title>Ejemplo</title>
    </head>
    <body>
    <input id="semilla" type="text">
    <script>
    let min = 200;
    let max = 300;
    let semrandom = Math.floor(Math.random() * max) + min;
    let semilla = document.getElementById("semilla")
    function soloImpares() {
      if (semrandom % 2 !== 0) {
       semilla.setAttribute("value", `${semrandom}`)
      } else {
       return false
      }
    }
      soloImpares()
    </script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: No le veo falla al código pero por alguna razón no me aparece nada en mi input. A que se deberá?

Comment: Es un input lo que estoy utilizando.

Comment: Mi error era que no había mandado a llamar la función, gracias. Ahora hay veces donde aparece un valor y recargo la pagina y no aparece nada en el input. A que se debera?

Comment: `Math.floor(Math.random() * max) + min` puede dar valores hasta 499, lo que esta fuera del máximo

Answer (score 2):

La función correcta para obtener un numero random entre dos intervalos enteros mayores que cero es `Math.floor((Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min)` podrás ver que tu función se va del rango máximo. Además no es necesaria ninguna recursión ni nada semejante porque siempre se obtiene un número impar a partir de un número par si a este le sumamos o le restamos 1.

```js
var min = 200;
var max = 300;
var semrandom = Math.floor((Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min);

var impar = semrandom;  

if(!(impar%2) && semrandom+1<max){
    impar = semrandom+1;
}

if(!(impar%2) && semrandom+1>max){
    impar = semrandom-1;
}

console.log(impar);
```

Con `Math.floor((Math.random() * max) + min);` el máximo es en realidad 499, 299 + 200, porque `Math.random()` nunca es 1 de manera que nunca puede ser 300 la primer parte.

Por otra parte, `max - min + 1` nos da el intervalo de números a los que estamos restringidos, el +1 es para incluír el número que nos falta porque `Math.random()` nunca es 1. `+min` es para correr el intetrvalo `min` veces.

Comment: porque haces dos veces al mismo if? error de transcripción o significa algo?

Comment: @JackNavaRow No son iguales, el segundo es para el caso que sea 300 (`semrandom+1>max`) , asi le restamos 1 para que se mantenga dentro del rango (299). En este caso justo es par, podríamos hacer `=== max` pero debería funcionar para cualquier minimo o maximo.