# Cómo generar un numero de 0 a 9 con javascript

Tags: javascript

Cómo puedo generar un numero al azar de 0 a 9 usando javascript? No he podido encontrar la manera de hacerlo.

```js
var counter = 0;


counter++;
```

Comment: Usa: Math.random()*9; Math.random(); generará numeros aleatorios al nivel decimal entre 0 y 1, al multiplicarlo con un entero te dará el resultado que quieres. Y me gusta tu nombre.

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [Generar números aleatorios de un rango dado](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/326331/generar-n%c3%bameros-aleatorios-de-un-rango-dado)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Puedes usar la random de la siguiente manera:

```js
function getRandomInt(min, max) {
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min)) + min;
}
counter = getRandomInt(0, 9);
console.log(counter)
```

Answer (score 2):

Puedes usar `Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1) + min);` donde `max = 9` y `min = 0`, quedaría así:

```
Math.floor(Math.random() * (9 - 0 + 1) + 0);
```

Answer (score 1):

### Uso de [`Math.random`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Math/random)

Este método es usado para generar un número decimal al azar

```js
console.log(Math.random())
```

Por defecto, genera un flotante al azar entre 0 hasta el 1, donde el valor de retorno **NUNCA** será *1*, pero **SÍ podrá ser 0**

Entonces tenemos

```js
console.log(Math.floor(Math.random() * 10))
```

Donde generaremos un número entre 0 y 9, el método `Math.floor` nos convertirá el flotante a un entero que podemos interpretar

---

#### Desde un string

El segundo método que encuentro sería hacer un bucle `for` desde el que podamos ir desde *min* hasta *max*, entonces, crearemos un *string* y lo iremos concatenando

De manera que tenemos

```
str += i * max - (max - min + i);
```

Luego de tener el string completo, lo que podemos hacer un *shuffle* (alternar sus letras)

```js
function random(min, max) {
  let str = "";
  for(let i = min; i <= max; i++) {
    str += (i * max - (min + i));
  }
  let a = str.split("")
  let n = a.length;
  for(let i = n - 1; i > 0; i--) {
        let j = Math.floor(Math.random() * (i + 1));
        let tmp = a[i];
        a[i] = a[j];
        a[j] = tmp;
  }
  return a.join().charAt(0);
}

console.log(random(0, 9));
```