# Alguien sabe si hay otra manera para escribir este codigo y que me regrese el mismo resultado

Tags: python

```
numbers = [1, 3, 25, 17, 6, 12, 9]

for number in numbers:
    if number % 2 == 0:
        print(f"This {number} is even.")
    else:
        print (f"This {number} is odd.")
```

Comment: [mira esta respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/124750/c%c3%b3mo-detectar-paridad-de-un-numero-sin-el-operador?r=SearchResults)

Answer (score 0):

No es muy distinto, pero puedes utilizar el operador ternario:

```
print(number," odd") if number%2 else print(number, " even")
```

Answer (score 0):

Lo puedes hacer con comprension de listas

```
[print(f"This {number} is even.") if number%2==0 else print (f"This {number} is odd.") for number in numbers ]
```

https://code.tutsplus.com/es/tutorials/list-comprehensions-in-python--cms-26836