# Como puedo saber los números impares de un array?

Tags: javascript

como puedo saber los números impares que hay en un array.

Lo quiero hacer con un bucle for algo como esto:

```js
let numeros = [ 80, 65, 35, 20, 42]
let impares = 0
for(let i = 0; i < numeros.length; i++)
  impares = numeros[i]
{
  if()
  alert('La cantidad de numeros impares que hay es: ' numeros[i] ++)
}
```

Creo que algo así sería, pero no se como es la formula del if para calcular los numeros impares.

Comment: Busca sobre el operador *%* será la solución s tu problema

Comment: Aquí entra un poco de sentido común. Los números impares son aquellos que solo se pueden dividir entre 2 y el residuo es 0. Como ya te comentaron, el operador `%` debería ayudarte con eso.

Comment: [Hay mas de una manera de hacerlo](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/124750/c%c3%b3mo-detectar-paridad-de-un-numero-sin-el-operador/124758#124758). Para gustos, los colores.

Answer (score 1):

Se puede realizar todo en una linea.

```js
const numeros = [ 80, 65, 35, 20, 42]
//Uso filter (que es un filtro en arreglo) para obtener solo los números que 
// tengan residuo 0.
const impares = numeros.filter(x=> x%2 === 0).length
console.log('La cantidad de numeros impares que hay es: ' + impares)
```

> ## [Operador `%`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/conflicting/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators#.25_.28modular.29)
>
> El operador resto devuelve el resto que queda cuando un operando se divide por un segundo operando. Siempre toma el signo del dividendo, no el divisor. Utiliza una función de modulo incorporada para producir el resultado, que es el resto entero de dividir var1 por var2 - por ejemplo - var1 modulo var2

> ## [`Array.filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)
>
> El método filter() crea un nuevo array con todos los elementos que cumplan la condición implementada por la función dada.